# How can I force the size of carousel into 4:3 ratio using bootstrap 4.4?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, carousel

I am trying to utilize [twitter-bootstrap 4.4](https://getbootstrap.com/) to create a carousel with thumbnails. But, I want to fir the image into a fixed 4:3 ratio container so I get a consistent look regardless of the image's orientation.

How can I force the `carousel-inner` container to show up as 4:3 ratio all the time? I have the following [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vwhe38Ls/4/) with the complete code

Here is a stripped-down version of my fiddle

```
<!--Carousel Wrapper-->
<div id="carousel-thumb" class="carousel slide carousel-fade carousel-thumbnails" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
  <!--Slides-->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <!--Image 1-->
    <figure class="carousel-item active">
      <picture class="d-block w-100">
        <img class="w-100" style="object-fit:cover;" src="https://photos.zillowstatic.com/cc_ft_768/ISv4f3q9br50lc0000000000.webp" alt="First slide">
      </picture>
      <figcaption class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">I am an image caption</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <!--/.Image 1-->
  </div>
  <!--/.Slides-->
  <!--Controls-->
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel-thumb" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel-thumb" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
  <!--/.Controls-->
  <!--Thumbnails-->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <!--Thumbnail 1-->
    <li data-target="#carousel-thumb" data-slide-to="0" class="active">
      <picture>
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://photos.zillowstatic.com/cc_ft_768/ISv4f3q9br50lc0000000000.webp" class="img-thumbnail">
      </picture>
    </li>
    <!--/.Thumbnail 1-->       
  </ol>
  <!--/.Thumbnails-->
</div>
<!--/.Carousel Wrapper-->
```

Answer (score 0):

By your question, your problem not defined perfectly but I tried and I come into the below solution, checkout!

Your code has `.w-100` class everywhere, I don't know why but please remove it from everywhere and uses CSS instead, If you want to apply `width: 100%;` in every image.

I added below CSS in your code

```
ol li img.w-100 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 6vw !important;
}

figure picture img.w-100 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 25rem;
}
```

`!important` used here because of overcoming `w-100` class `!important`.

https://jsfiddle.net/q9d3w17v/1/

Comment: That is closer to what I am looking for. My main objective is to make a large image appear in a fixed view of 4:3. If the width of `carousel-inner` is calculated `800px`, then the height will have to be `600px`. The image will have to fill up the box without changing its height. I tried to change my code to include your recommendation, but still, the code is not working as desired. If you click on the last image, you'll see how the height of the `carousel-inner` increases. Additionally, the thumbnails are currently too small. Updated code https://jsfiddle.net/0f3yoctd/1/

Comment: please check this URL https://jsfiddle.net/5zaw28tj, you forgot to put `height: 25rem` in your code, so your last image will increase the height

Comment: But adding `25rem` does not give me 4:3 ratio. I think `25rem` is similar for 25% of the HTML's root. To get the 4:3 ratio the height must be 75% of the `carousel-inner` width all the time regardless of the actual width of `carousel-inner`

Comment: you find your answer?

Comment: I still have not found a solution. Here is the latest fiddle that I am working on. https://jsfiddle.net/uz9qpboL/1/

Comment: why you need 4:3 ratio if your work is done by adding 25rem height?

Comment: because on a large screen 25rem will hide lots of the picture details. Having 4:3 ration will ensure that the picture is fully visible, Also, most of the pictures I have are sized to fir 4:3 ratio.